# Load jquery in asp.net page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, load

I'm using asp.net c# and jquery

I created a page with two updatepanel (UpdateMode = conditional) and within each there is a form with search filters (name, description, etc.)

Each form has a button that when pressed will display advanced search options through an effect created in jQuery (function ToggleAdvOptions, when you click on the button expands a div and when you return to press contracts)

To load the jquery functions use the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
        function load() {
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_endRequest(function () {
            BindEvents();
        });
    }
```

Then I call the function load (), from the body onload event of the page:

```
<body onload="load();">
```

The problem is that if I do a postback from the UpdatePanel1, and then I click on the button to show advanced options UpdatePanel2, ToggleAdvOptions function is executed twice. The effect is that the resulting div expands and then contracts

Anyone know how to solve the problem?

Best Regards

Comment: I don't know, maybe I'm missing something but I think you are missing some jQuery code here in your question?

Comment: That's really the "issue" with update panels, they reload the whole page and then just dump the relevant content into the panel. Because of this you're binding the same event twice, can you not just do a stright `$(selector).click(function() {})` instead?

Comment: I would look into not using update panels at all. I found them to be too much of a pain, and replaced them with ajax calls.
See this blog post:
http://encosia.com/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the following already on your page:

1. A ScriptManager control.
2. You have declared triggers on your updatepanel controls, e.g.

   ```
                <Triggers>
                  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
                </Triggers>
   ```

If it differs, or is still not working with the triggers declared, a bit more code should help enormously for us to understand the problem you are facing.